# How can I set different prices to the frontpage of a magento webshop

Tags: php, magento

I am working on a Magento webshop and because it is a webshop of gold and silver it needs to have responsive prices. when you add the item to a cart it calculates the value but on the frontpage and the category page it has a set  value.

As the event we use this:

```
<catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    <observers>
        <webshop>
            <class>webshope/observer</class>
            <method>updateCatalogPrice</method>
        </webshop>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_collection_load_after>
```

And this is the php function:

```
public function updateCatalogPrice($observer) {
    if (!strpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], 'admin')) { 

        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $myCustomPrice = 32.50;
        $products = $observer->getCollection();

        foreach( $products as $product ) { 
            //$product->setPrice( $myCustomPrice );
            $product->setFinalPrice($myCustomPrice );
        } 
        return $this;
    }

    return this;
}
```

This calculated the price:

```
public function CalculatePrice($product) {

    if ($product->dynamicprice == '243') { //dynamic price

        $xml=simplexml_load_file('../MagentoAssets/ResponsivePrices/test.xml');

        $prijsGold = (float)$xml->Gold;
        $prijsSilver = (float)$xml->Silver;

        if($product->grondstof == '241'){ //gold    
            $weight = $product->weight;         
            $result = $weight*$prijsGold; 
            $result = sprintf("%.2f", $result);
        }

        elseif($product->grondstof == '240'){ //silver 
            $weight = $product->weight;
            $result = $weight*$prijsSilver;
            $result = sprintf("%.2f", $result);
        }

        return $result;

    }
    else{ //manual price
        return $product->price;
    }   
}
```

For some reason the `<catalog_product_collection_load_after>` does not give a dynamic value and the "grondstof"(dutch for resource the item is made of)
so my question is: how do I make this event give the dynamic value and the other one, or a event that can achieve the same thing?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40015/display-custom-attributes-outside-the-product-page-view-phtml this worked for me